# Dual booting No efi system found was found Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I really want to dual boot my laptop and the problem that during installation, it says "no efi system partition was found". I quit the installation and my windows is still boot normally so i think i didnt delete some necessary files.

This is what my disk management looks like
[disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGUQv.png)

i already did a partition for the ubuntu.
my bios mode is in legacy mode.

So i plugged the bootable usb and this is what the boot menu (boot priority order)looks like
[boot priority order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrPli.jpg) , this is also what my secure boot configurations
[secure boot configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Ly1.jpg) and i also disable the fastboot.

Pic during installation process
[Ubuntu installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAuQ1.jpg)

and I proceed in selecting "something else"

this is where i'm stuck, I cant continue because it says "no efi system partition was found"
[Ubuntu installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2tjQ.jpg)

Is there a way to fix this without deleting the windows 10?
please help me.

Comment: Windows only installs in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode to MBR drives. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so most hardware is UEFI and should have UEFI installs. BIOS mode really only for systems over 10 years old. If you do not reinstall Windows, then you need to install Ubuntu in BIOS mode. If installing on same MBR(msdos) drive then you need to boot installer in BIOS mode to get BIOS install. Better to reinstall Windows in UEFI mode if newer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I think your system (Board) is UEFI.
if you click on "Something else" then you must create some essential files such:

> / , root , home , swap , efi

click on "freespace" and then create those files.
follow this instrcution for deep informations:
[Click](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)